# ROBLOX - how to tell who killed an enemy

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm aware of the Humanoid.Died connect event, but how do you know who(what player) killed the enemy? And where would you run the Humanoid.Died event?

Comment: How does the kill script work? If it’s all based on a “giver” script (the script is in the weapon and damages the other player) then you can just check the parent of the tool, for example.